# Java Applets prompt for update/block/later; updated to requested version, then newest version

Tags: java, applet, updates

Any applet I click on from the web prompts me to update Java, even though I had the most recent version. The prompt directed me to a download (on the real Java site, don't worry) so I installed it. I went back to the applet, and the prompt persisted.

I searched for help and found another forum post that said the prompt directs you to an outdated version of Java - it's a bug in the Applet manager. Okay, I downloaded the newest version of Java available on the website and had it uninstall all older versions on my computer. I looked at another applet, and the prompt was still there.

What am I doing wrong? Applets in general can't be broken - they must have tested it.

```
C:\...>java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

If I understand correctly, the applet version can be different than your regular version of Java. When I go to http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp, I get the same prompt, but the filename is marked with (2), because I've downloaded it and installed it twice.

Update: I visited the same page again, and Java crashed, nearly taking out my browser in the process. It recovered and told me it needed to uninstall 8 update 5 so it could install 8 update 20, but it failed to uninstall (probably because it crashed Java.) Meanwhile, checking in Programs and Features, as well as the -version check I posted above, I can see that version 8 update 20 is installed.

I'll post the updates as I go - I'm uninstalling all Java from my machine in the hopes that one was interfering with the other somehow.

Comment: I assume your machine to be x86_64 architecture.If so, in that case,I know the reason!

Comment: It is, yes. 
Updating: I manually purged all the versions of Java I could find, then went through the whole process again. The uninstaller found version 8 update 5 (apparently Windows didn't have it indexed as an installed program?) and installed 8 update 20. Now all applets are "working" - but they're blocked by default, and after allowing them to run, they're blocked by the security manager, because the "medium" security setting is removed. Every applet I've found since appears to be blocked like this.

Comment: FYI I'm using 64-bit Chrome (dev), 64-bit Java, etc. I'm not aware of any conflicts there. Also, Eclipse and the Java programs I write work fine, it's just applets that are getting blocked.